# Assume g (x) = sin(x) + 4. Complete the following table and then graph g (x)

Tags: trigonometry

My trig is a little rusty and I don't recall how I would get started on completing this table. Any guidance is appreciated, thank you.

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3EGc.png)

Comment: Are you unable to recall the sines of the angles given on the left?

Comment: I suggest you draw your unit circle and familiarize yourself with the values of $\sin x$ at key values of $x.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $\sin0=\sin180=\sin360=0$; $\sin90=1$; $\sin270=-1$

Comment: So for the first  value of x = 0, the value of g(x) would be sin 0 + 4 which is 4?

Comment: @Victoria Yes but I suggest you to convert (on x-axis) from degree to radiant when you'll draw the graph.